# Playlists of playlists on YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Is it possible to have a playlist which contains other playlists on YouTube?

For example I have a playlist named 'Jazz' which contains jazz music, and a playlist called 'Rock' which contains rock.

Is it possible to create a playlist named 'Music' which contains both and adds from both when I add to either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was [asked for in 2009](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/UTE4TPh9dlQ) but still has not been implemented.

Source: Personal testing